# Usage of すら in この中ではそれすら異常なスピードで進むというのか

Tags: grammar

Just want to confirm my understanding. From what I can tell, すら means 'even'.

So in a sentence like:
"この中ではそれすら異常なスピードで進むというのか" is my understanding correct that それすら is referring to the 異常なスピード?

Roughly translated my understanding is something like: "So this means its progressing at even that abnormal speed in here?"

Comment: We need to see the previous sentence(s) to know what the それ "it/that" refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this それ is just "it" or "that", and refers to some moving/progressing thing (eg, a vehicle, a program, a chemical reaction) mentioned in the previous context.

> この中では**それすら**異常なスピードで進むというのか。
> So, in here, **even that** progresses at extraordinary speeds?

"That abnormal speed" is そんな異常なスピード or そのような異常なスピード:

> この中では**そのような**異常なスピードで進むというのか。
> So, in here, [it] progresses at an extraordinary speed **like that**?
> So, in here, [it] progresses at **such** an extraordinary speed?